# Nested if statement in Power Query

Tags: excel-2013, powerquery

I discovered and started using Power Query yesterday. I have written some queries to populate three drop down lists, with the second and third dependent on what is selected in the first, and the third then further dependent on what is selected in the second.

When I am creating the list of possible items in these lists I am adding an “All” record at the top of each as part of my queries. I have used an if statement when populating the second list that essentially says *if user has selected All in the first box, go get all records, otherwise bring back records where the value in a particular column equals what has been selected in that first list*.

However, as the third list requires a check to see if “All” has been selected in both the first and second list box, I believe I need to do two if statements. I have searched the internet all afternoon yesterday to find an example of two nested if statements with limited success, and whenever I try to do it myself I get a variety of syntax errors that I am missing a token Eof or token then or a comma is missing and so on.

Would anyone be able to show me a simple example of how to lay out nested if statements please?

Thank you

UPDATE:

Thank you for your answer. I am still having real problems. Here is my query, which currently works.

```
if Wholesaler_Cmbo_Lnkd_Cell <> "All wholesalers" then

let

    Source = Table.SelectRows(Query_GSR, each [Wholesaler number] = Wholesaler_Cmbo_Lnkd_Cell),
    #"GroupedSource" = Table.Group(Source, {"Month_Name", "Year_No", "Item Category", "Item Category Type", "Tariff status", "Weekday","Transaction type","Group number","Customer account number"}, {{"Gross sales", each List.Sum([Gross sales])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Rebates", each List.Sum([Rebates])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Net sales", each List.Sum([Net sales])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Direct materials", each List.Sum([Direct materials])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Packaging", each List.Sum([Packaging])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Lab consumables", each List.Sum([Lab consumables])},
                                                                                                                                            {"QC costs", each List.Sum([QC costs])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Stock adjustments", each List.Sum([Stock adjustments])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Product margin", each List.Sum([Product margin])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Gross profit", each List.Sum([Gross profit])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Carriage income", each List.Sum([Carriage income])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Carriage expense", each List.Sum([Carriage expense])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Orders", each List.Count([ID])}})
in

    #"GroupedSource" 

else

let

    Source = Query_GSR,
    #"GroupedSource" = Table.Group(Source, {"Month_Name", "Year_No", "Item Category", "Item Category Type", "Tariff status", "Weekday", "Transaction type", "Group number", "Customer account number"}, {{"Gross sales", each List.Sum([Gross sales])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Rebates", each List.Sum([Rebates])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Net sales", each List.Sum([Net sales])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Direct materials", each List.Sum([Direct materials])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Packaging", each List.Sum([Packaging])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Lab consumables", each List.Sum([Lab consumables])},
                                                                                                                                            {"QC costs", each List.Sum([QC costs])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Stock adjustments", each List.Sum([Stock adjustments])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Product margin", each List.Sum([Product margin])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Gross profit", each List.Sum([Gross profit])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Carriage income", each List.Sum([Carriage income])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Carriage expense", each List.Sum([Carriage expense])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Orders", each List.Count([ID])}})
in

    #"GroupedSource"
```

I know my layout is awful - something to work on. I would much rather it looked like this:

```
if Wholesaler_Cmbo_Lnkd_Cell <> "All wholesalers" then

let

    Source = Table.SelectRows(Query_GSR, each [Wholesaler number] = Wholesaler_Cmbo_Lnkd_Cell)

in

    Source

else

let

    Source = Query_GSR

in

    Source

let

    #"GroupedSource" = Table.Group(Source, {"Month_Name", "Year_No", "Item Category", "Item Category Type", "Tariff status", "Weekday", "Transaction type", "Group number", "Customer account number"}, {{"Gross sales", each List.Sum([Gross sales])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Rebates", each List.Sum([Rebates])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Net sales", each List.Sum([Net sales])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Direct materials", each List.Sum([Direct materials])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Packaging", each List.Sum([Packaging])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Lab consumables", each List.Sum([Lab consumables])},
                                                                                                                                            {"QC costs", each List.Sum([QC costs])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Stock adjustments", each List.Sum([Stock adjustments])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Product margin", each List.Sum([Product margin])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Gross profit", each List.Sum([Gross profit])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Carriage income", each List.Sum([Carriage income])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Carriage expense", each List.Sum([Carriage expense])},
                                                                                                                                            {"Orders", each List.Count([ID])}})


in

    #"GroupedSource"
```

Its saying a token Eof is expected, and when I have tried to wrap the entire thing in another "let" and "in", it says a token comma is expected on the first #"GroupedSource". I have tried all sorts of additional "in" and "let" inclusions but clearly I am missing a fundamental understanding of how "let", "in" and assigning answers to "variables" works.

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can achieve the same with Table.SelectRows (the Power Query equivalent to a filter in Excel).  Your code modified below.

```html
let
    Source = Query_GSR,
    
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Orders", each if [Transaction type] = "Credit" then -1 else 1),
    
    Narrow = if Wholesaler_Cmbo_Lnkd_Cell = "" then #"Added Custom"
        else if Wholesaler_Cmbo_Lnkd_Cell = "All wholesalers" then #"Added Custom"
        else Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each [Wholesaler number] = Wholesaler_Cmbo_Lnkd_Cell)
    
in
    Narrow
```

Hope it helps.  You might want to use data validation on the Wholesaler_Cmbo_Lnkd_Cell input.

Jake

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this. Yes there is another query that loads to a single column table that I’m in the drop down cell to drive data validation. One other question if you don’t mind please - what’s the difference between something that is preceded by a # and is in quotes (such as #”Added Custom”) and Narrow in your modified code?

Comment: *I’m using in the drop down

Comment: Sure.  Each new line of code in Power Query is a "step".  PQ (Power Query) default is to create step names with spaces in them, like "Promote Headers".  If there is a space in a step name, it will add the hashtag and quotes.  If it's a bother to you, you can right click each step in the UI and Rename with no spaces - that will kill the hashtags and quotes.  It's the default, that's all.

Comment: Ah ok got it. Thank you very much for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

Nested if statements look like this inside PowerQuery:

```
if [condition1]
    then (if [condition2] then [true1-true2 result] else [true1-false2 result])
    else [false result]
```

You can also add an if to the else condition:

```
if [condition1]
    then (if [condition2] then [true1-true2 result]  else [true1-false2 result])
    else (if [condition3] then [false1-true3 result] else [false1-false3 result])
```

Comment: Thank you. I have added some more information to my original question as I think this is what I'm doing but I am still having issues.

Answer (score 0):

Ok came at this completely differently and this is probably me learning how to use Power Query properly. I achieved the same thing with the following code:

```
let
    Source = Query_GSR,
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Orders", each if [Transaction type] = "Credit" then -1 else 1),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "WorkOutFilter", each if Wholesaler_Cmbo_Lnkd_Cell = "All wholesalers" then "Keep" else if [Wholesaler number] = Wholesaler_Cmbo_Lnkd_Cell then "Keep" else "Remove"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom1", each ([WorkOutFilter] = "Keep")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"WorkOutFilter"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Unbelievable. I need to think less like I'm writing code and more like this, where I use if statements on each record rather than in the code!

Thank you again for your help - it did help the penny drop.